# How can I escape from a null checking when calling a API image

Tags: flutter

When I use to call an image by API it shows it need a null Checker

```
DownloadsImageWidget(
                    imageList:
                        '$imageAppendUrl${state.downloads?[1].posterPath}',
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                    size: Size(
                      size.width * 0.4,
                      size.height * 0.30,
                    ),
                  ),
```

I tried to put a null checker ? , then I will never get a image because of wrong URL.
its  shows this error:

> HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https‍://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500null

When I tried to give ! `Null check operator used on a null value` I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to add a ternary operator to check whether your `state.downloads` is not null:

```
DownloadsImageWidget(
  imageList: state.downloads == null ? null : '$imageAppendUrl${state.downloads[1]?.posterPath}',
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
  size: Size(
    size.width * 0.4,
    size.height * 0.30,
  ),
),
```

Comment: what's the point of checking for null if you are going to pass null value anyways.

Comment: @SiddharthMehra OP didn't provide any information about the desired behavior of his code in case he gets null from his API request. The idea was to eliminate the case where "null" is passed to a url.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the posterPath is the non-null attribute.

Then you can check if the `downloads` is empty or not before passing its list item.

Example:

```
if(state.downloads.isNotEmpty)
  DownloadsImageWidget(
    imageList: '$imageAppendUrl${state.downloads?[1].posterPath}',
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
    size: Size(size.width * 0.4,size.height * 0.30),
  ),
```